# CGAL: Using the type `Mark` while exploring a plane map

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

The CGAL online documentation about `CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_2<T>::Topological_explorer` (please see [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Nef_2/classCGAL_1_1Nef__polyhedron__2_1_1Topological__explorer.html)) mentions a type `Mark` and a number of functions, which return a value of this type:

```
const Mark &    mark (Vertex_const_handle v)
    returns the mark of v.

const Mark &    mark (Halfedge_const_handle e)
    returns the mark of e.

const Mark &    mark (Face_const_handle f)
    returns the mark of f.
```

The documentation says: "Plane maps are attributed, for each object we attribute an information `mark(u)` of type `Mark`. Mark fits the concepts assignable, default-constructible, and equal-comparable."

What's the idea behind this type and values? How am I supposed to use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to explore a plane map, you need to traverse elements (halfedges and/or vertices and/or faces). You can for example use a depth search first algorithm as for graph traversal.

During such traversal, it is often necessary to test if an element is already discovered of not. This can be achieved thanks to a Boolean mark which is set to true when an element is discovered.

By default in Nef_2, Mark is a bool, but this can be changed thanks to an undocumented template parameter (see [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/5a02f47c56a4d2084e20688bb2817e2017b363ef/Nef_2/include/CGAL/Nef_polyhedron_2.h#L124)). For example you can use an int if you want to store the time where an element is discovered.

See also [this example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Nef_2/index.html#Nef_2Exploration).

Comment: Thank you - however, I don't see any way to *set* marks on map elements. Could you please give me a hint?